# Give a non-recursive definition for the language L

Tags: computer-science, recursion, formal-languages

Consider the following recursive definition for $L ⊆ \{a, b\}^* : b ∈ L; ∀w ∈ L, bw, wa \text{ and } aw$ are in $L$. Give a non-recursive definition for L (using Kleene star or in English)

I'm trying to answer this problem, but I'm struggling finding the good answer using the Kleen star

Can someone explain me?

Comment: Start by finding examples of strings that are in L (by applying the given production rules to $b$ and then to every new string you get). Then try to describe the resulting set of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition tells you that every word in $L$ can be formed by starting with $b$ and repeatedly adding an $a$ or a $b$ at the beginning or an $a$ at the end. For instance, the derivation

$$\color{red}b\overset{bw}\longrightarrow b\color{red}b\overset{aw}\longrightarrow ab\color{red}b\overset{bw}\longrightarrow bab\color{red}b\overset{wa}\longrightarrow bab\color{red}ba\overset{aw}\longrightarrow abab\color{red}ba\overset{wa}\longrightarrow abab\color{red}baa$$

shows a derivation of the word $ababbaa\in L$; above each arrow I’ve indicated which rule I’m using for that step. I’ve also colored the initial $\color{red}b$ red.

- What kinds of strings can appear to the left of the initial $b$?
- What kinds of strings can appear to the right of the initial $b$?

By looking at some examples and thinking about the rules for constructing members of $L$ you should be able to answer these two questions, and when you’ve done that, you’ve essentially described which words are in $L$. Once you can describe $L$ in words, we can help you describe $L$ symbolically with the aid of the Kleene star.

Comment: Ok! I find that the kind of strings that can appear to the right of the initial $b$ are only strings that contains only $a$'s , i.e, strings of the form $a^n$, $n \geq 0$

Comment: But I'm struggling to define de kind of strings that can appear to the left, I mean you can have like $a^{3} b^{4} a^{5} b^{6}$ to the left of the initial $b$

Comment: @Massimo2015MX: You’re right about the strings to the right of that initial $b$. For the strings to the left, can you answer this question: is there any string of $a$s and $b$s that can**not** appear to the left?

Comment: By looking at some examples I made, I think any combination of $a$'s and $b$'s can appear at the right of the initial $b$. So if I'm not wrong, I just answer the question, right?

Comment: @Massimo2015MX: Yes, that’s right. So the language is $\{a,b\}^*ba^*$.

Comment: Ohhh now I see it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Massimo2015MX: You’re welcome!